# Angular - Using the same module for multiple paths

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-lazyloading

A bit of a code structure question for Angular. I’m trying to achieve a split screen design, where the left and right show different data, based on different queries. The left will usually dictate which data on the right is display.

For example: The left will have a list of Artists. When clicking on an artist, a list of their albums will appear on the right.  One approach that worked, but doesn’t feel quite right is the following:

A “screen one” component that has access to the URL params. Inside this component / module we import the Artists component and the Projects component. The screen one component handles the queries to Firestore and hands them down to these components:

```
<div>
    <app-artists [artistsArray]="artistsArray"></app-artists>
    <app-albums [albumsArray]="albumsArray"></app-albums>
</div>
```

This works pretty well. However, this will appear at the route `/artists` . When clicking on an artists, the route would then be `/artists/:artistID`. The tricky part here, is that in my routing module, i now have two routes that load the exact same module. Is that an issue?
Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'artists',
    loadChildren: () => import('./screens/screen-one/screen-one.module').then(mod => mod.ScreenOneModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'artists/:artistID',
    loadChildren: () => import('./screens/screen-one/screen-one.module').then(mod => mod.ScreenOneModule),
  },
];
```

Comment: remove artists/:artistID, create artists.routes.ts, import it from your screenOneModule, and put your children in the create routes

Comment: Thanks! - Are you able to demonstrate that in an answer please?

Comment: sure, let's see if it works

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue but it's recommended to split your app routes. Let's say you have an AppModule that contains 3 big modules. It's better having the main app-routing.module and a route module for each big module then having it in the same app-routing.module.

remove artists/:artistID, create artists.routes.ts, import it from your screenOneModule, and put your children in the created route

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'artists',
    loadChildren: () => import('./screens/screen-one/screen-one.module').then(mod => mod.ScreenOneModule),
  }
];
...
```

**artists.routes.ts**

```
...
export const routes: Routes = [
    path: 'artists',
    children: [
        {
            path: ':artistID',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            component: ArtistsComponent
        }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
export class ArtistRoutes{}
```

**screen-one.module.ts**

```
...
imports: [
    ...
    ArtistRoutes,
    ...
]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, what you suggested isn't an issue**. You could also map an array of routes:

```
const artistPaths: string[] = ['artist', 'artists/:artistID'];
const artistRoutes: Route[] = artistPaths.map((path) => ({path, loadChildren: () => null}));
```

Then either:

1. Push this into the routes array:

```
routes.push(artistRoutes);
```

2. Add it in the array definition directly:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  artistRoutes  
];
```